# необходимо выделить элементы из словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, vkontakte-api, dict

есть ответ от сервера:

```
{'response': 
{'count': 626, 'items': 
[
{'id': 899, 'from_id': -137348293, 'owner_id': -137348293, 'date': 1520918104, 'marked_as_ads': 0, 'post_type': 'post', 'text': 'Глава компании SpaceX Илон Маск, а также его друг Джонатан Нолан (сценарист фильма «Интерстеллар» и режиссёр сериала «Мир Дикого Запада») презентовали новое видео запуска Falcon Heavy с автомобилем Tesla на борту', 'can_delete': 1, 'can_pin': 1, 'attachments': [{'type': 'link', 'link': {'url': 'http://gp.by/category/news/novosti-mira/news176200.html', 'title': 'Илон Маск и Джонатан Нолан опубликовали новый ролик о запуске Tesla в космос : Правда Гомель', 'caption': 'gp.by', 'description': 'Глава компании SpaceX Илон Маск, а также его друг Джонатан Нолан (сценарист фильма «Интерстеллар» и режиссёр сериала «Мир Дикого Запада») презентовали новое видео запуска Falcon Heavy с автомобилем Tesla на борту.', 'photo': {'id': 456274848, 'album_id': -2, 'owner_id': 97910852, 'photo_75': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c840122/v840122979/80f01/LoeRC5xc5AM.jpg', 'photo_130': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c840122/v840122979/80f02/nzLfEKXj5YA.jpg', 'photo_604': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c840122/v840122979/80f03/sdlYI9Nr0Y8.jpg', 'width': 150, 'height': 83, 'text': '', 'date': 1520918108}}}], 'post_source': {'type': 'api'}, 'comments': {'count': 0, 'groups_can_post': True, 'can_post': 1}, 'likes': {'count': 0, 'user_likes': 0, 'can_like': 1, 'can_publish': 1}, 'reposts': {'count': 0, 'user_reposted': 0}, 'views': {'count': 364}}, 
{'id': 898, 'from_id': -137348293, 'owner_id': -137348293, 'date': 1520892300, 'marked_as_ads': 0, 'post_type': 'post', 'text': 'Авторы YouTube-канала NIXOLAS пофантазировали над тем, как будет выглядеть наша планета, если на ней останутся только роботы Boston Dynamics.\n\nВидео вызвало огромный интерес и волну обсуждений в Сети', 'can_delete': 1, 'can_pin': 1, 'attachments': [{'type': 'link', 'link': {'url': 'https://iz.ru/718103/2018-03-09/poiavilos-video-posledstvii-zakhvata-zemli-robotami', 'title': 'Появилось видео последствий «захвата» Земли роботами', 'caption': 'iz.ru', 'description': 'Авторы YouTube-канала NIXOLAS пофантазировали над тем, как будет выглядеть наша планета, если на ней останутся только роботы Boston Dynamics. Видео вызвало огромный интерес и волну обсуждений в Сети. В ролике авторы попытались представить облик Земли, если осуществится один из самых растиражированных «сценариев апокалипсиса» –– «восстание машин». При этом авторы предлагают представить, что на план', 'photo': {'id': 456274847, 'album_id': -2, 'owner_id': 97910852, 'photo_75': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c840133/v840133581/88c1d/BH18hr1YvM4.jpg', 'photo_130': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c840133/v840133581/88c1e/rsRQE_XtGH0.jpg', 'photo_604': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c840133/v840133581/88c1f/-gGpgAkSAxI.jpg', 'width': 150, 'height': 84, 'text': '', 'date': 1520892302}, 'preview_url': 'https://m.vk.com/article1180816951_864120627?api_view=b048b51fcc0406cb538549eb55b197', 'preview_page': '1180816951_864120627'}}], 'post_source': {'type': 'api'}, 'comments': {'count': 0, 'groups_can_post': True, 'can_post': 1}, 'likes': {'count': 0, 'user_likes': 0, 'can_like': 1, 'can_publish': 1}, 'reposts': {'count': 0, 'user_reposted': 0}, 'views': {'count': 343}}
]
}
}
```

`'id': 898,` - пост в ВК. Необходимо создать список, элементы которого будут информацией по каждому списку. Окончательная цель - создание таблицы в mysql. Создать таблицу я смогу сам, а вот разделить ответ сервера на элементы я сам не могу.

Я попробовал вот такой вариант:

```
post_list = [x[0] for x in r['response']['items']]
```

Получил вот такой стек:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/perforce/Social/VK_stats_get.py", line 48, in <module>
    vk_post_processing.vk_post_processing(gid)
  File "D:\perforce\Social\vk_post_processing.py", line 24, in vk_post_processing
    post_list = [x[0] for x in r['response']['items']]
  File "D:\perforce\Social\vk_post_processing.py", line 24, in <listcomp>
    post_list = [x[0] for x in r['response']['items']]
KeyError: 0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `[x[0] for x in rs['response']['items']]`

Comment: я сделал вот так: post_list = [x[0] for x in r['response']['items']]

Comment: получил вот такую ошибку:
    post_list = [x[0] for x in r['response']['items']]
KeyError: 0

Comment: так `{a1}` это словарь?

Comment: я всегда считал, что все, что находится между {} = это словарь или dict

Comment: хорошо, я ошибся, это не словарь. А как тогда код поменять?

Comment: есть длинный стек данных:

Answer (score 2):

Как насчет такого?

```
rs = {'response':{'count':626,'items':[{'id':899,'from_id':-137348293,'owner_id':-137348293,'date':1520918104,'marked_as_ads':0,'post_type':'post','text':'Глава компании SpaceX Илон Маск, а также его друг Джонатан Нолан (сценарист фильма «Интерстеллар» и режиссёр сериала «Мир Дикого Запада») презентовали новое видео запуска Falcon Heavy с автомобилем Tesla на борту','can_delete':1,'can_pin':1,'attachments':[{'type':'link','link':{'url':'http://gp.by/category/news/novosti-mira/news176200.html','title':'Илон Маск и Джонатан Нолан опубликовали новый ролик о запуске Tesla в космос : Правда Гомель','caption':'gp.by','description':'Глава компании SpaceX Илон Маск, а также его друг Джонатан Нолан (сценарист фильма «Интерстеллар» и режиссёр сериала «Мир Дикого Запада») презентовали новое видео запуска Falcon Heavy с автомобилем Tesla на борту.','photo':{'id':456274848,'album_id':-2,'owner_id':97910852,'photo_75':'https://pp.userapi.com/c840122/v840122979/80f01/LoeRC5xc5AM.jpg','photo_130':'https://pp.userapi.com/c840122/v840122979/80f02/nzLfEKXj5YA.jpg','photo_604':'https://pp.userapi.com/c840122/v840122979/80f03/sdlYI9Nr0Y8.jpg','width':150,'height':83,'text':'','date':1520918108}}}],'post_source':{'type':'api'},'comments':{'count':0,'groups_can_post':True,'can_post':1},'likes':{'count':0,'user_likes':0,'can_like':1,'can_publish':1},'reposts':{'count':0,'user_reposted':0},'views':{'count':364}},{'id':898,'from_id':-137348293,'owner_id':-137348293,'date':1520892300,'marked_as_ads':0,'post_type':'post','text':'Авторы YouTube-канала NIXOLAS пофантазировали над тем, как будет выглядеть наша планета, если на ней останутся только роботы Boston Dynamics.\n\nВидео вызвало огромный интерес и волну обсуждений в Сети','can_delete':1,'can_pin':1,'attachments':[{'type':'link','link':{'url':'https://iz.ru/718103/2018-03-09/poiavilos-video-posledstvii-zakhvata-zemli-robotami','title':'Появилось видео последствий «захвата» Земли роботами','caption':'iz.ru','description':'Авторы YouTube-канала NIXOLAS пофантазировали над тем, как будет выглядеть наша планета, если на ней останутся только роботы Boston Dynamics. Видео вызвало огромный интерес и волну обсуждений в Сети. В ролике авторы попытались представить облик Земли, если осуществится один из самых растиражированных «сценариев апокалипсиса» –– «восстание машин». При этом авторы предлагают представить, что на план','photo':{'id':456274847,'album_id':-2,'owner_id':97910852,'photo_75':'https://pp.userapi.com/c840133/v840133581/88c1d/BH18hr1YvM4.jpg','photo_130':'https://pp.userapi.com/c840133/v840133581/88c1e/rsRQE_XtGH0.jpg','photo_604':'https://pp.userapi.com/c840133/v840133581/88c1f/-gGpgAkSAxI.jpg','width':150,'height':84,'text':'','date':1520892302},'preview_url':'https://m.vk.com/article1180816951_864120627?api_view=b048b51fcc0406cb538549eb55b197','preview_page':'1180816951_864120627'}}],'post_source':{'type':'api'},'comments':{'count':0,'groups_can_post':True,'can_post':1},'likes':{'count':0,'user_likes':0,'can_like':1,'can_publish':1},'reposts':{'count':0,'user_reposted':0},'views':{'count':343}}]}}

post_list = rs['response']['items']
print('items ({}): {}'.format(len(post_list), post_list))  # items (2): [{'id': 899, 'from_i, ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться Pandas:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
import pandas as pd

db_connection = 'mysql+pymysql://mysql_user:mysql_password@mysql_host/mysql_db'
conn = create_engine(db_connection)

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(rs['response']['items']).rename(columns=lambda c: c.replace('.','_'))

df.to_sql('table_name', conn, if_exists='append')
```

PS код для создания `rs` я позаимствовал из [ответа @gil9red](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820560/211923)

---

Как выглядит DataFrame полученный из словаря:

```
In [34]: df
Out[34]:
                                         attachments  can_delete  can_pin  comments_can_post  comments_count  \
0  [{'type': 'link', 'link': {'url': 'http://gp.b...           1        1                  1               0
1  [{'type': 'link', 'link': {'url': 'https://iz....           1        1                  1               0

   comments_groups_can_post        date    from_id   id  likes_can_like     ...      likes_count  likes_user_likes  marked_as_ads  \
0                      True  1520918104 -137348293  899               1     ...                0                 0              0
1                      True  1520892300 -137348293  898               1     ...                0                 0              0

    owner_id  post_source_type post_type reposts_count  reposts_user_reposted                                               text  \
0 -137348293               api      post             0                      0  Глава компании SpaceX Илон Маск, а также его д...
1 -137348293               api      post             0                      0  Авторы YouTube-канала NIXOLAS пофантазировали ...

  views_count
0         364
1         343

[2 rows x 21 columns]
```